# Getting Wrong data on console

Tags: angular

I just passing some data as url and trying to console on next page from URL. But getting data in wrong variable.

> vendor-action.component.html

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['nVendorId','change_column','change_type','Timestamp','status','requestid']"></tr>
 <tr class="rowhover" (click)="displayData(row.change_column,row.nVendorId,row.requestid)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['nVendorId','change_column','change_type','Timestamp','status','requestid']"></tr>
```

> vendor-action.component.ts

```
displayData(col,id,rid)
{
 this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action/approval",col,id,rid]);
}
```

> approval.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.col=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('col');
    this.id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.rid=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('rid');

    console.log(this.col);
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.rid);
  }
```

I am getting value of "rid" in "col", "col" in "id" and "null" in "rid".
Why this is happening. Is something wrong in this?

Comment: It'd be better if you post your route configuration.

Comment: You can use NavigationExtras.You can't send variables like the way you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add those 3 variables in your routing information